# CentOS iptables MASQUERADE is not working for certain packets?

Tags: iptables

It's a bit weird that, some of the packets when going out of bwgla interface, it doesn't translate the source IP into that interface(10.0.12.102), in order to show this, please check below:

This is the packet capture from bwgla interface, as you see, all the packets are either comes from 10.0.12.102, or sent to 10.0.2.102, which is the IP of bwgla interface, that's how MASQUERADE works.

```
[root@box2 ~]# tcpdump -i bwgla -nn
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on bwgla, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
14:37:44.186195 IP 10.0.12.102.19201 > 54.191.53.147.443: Flags [P.], seq 2178927353:2178927388, ack 90788915, win 16360, length 35
14:37:44.191087 IP 10.0.12.102.52741 > 216.239.32.116.443: Flags [S], seq 2086226093, win 8192, options [mss 1386,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop], length 0
14:37:44.242792 IP 17.252.204.160.5223 > 10.0.12.102.61294: Flags [S.], seq 1671923054, ack 3897542686, win 28960, options [mss 1413,sackOK,TS val 3471677459 ecr 685711526,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:37:44.342166 IP 17.252.204.93.5223 > 10.0.12.102.61292: Flags [S.], seq 2114352723, ack 1911140225, win 28960, options [mss 1413,sackOK,TS val 3472692506 ecr 685711127,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:37:44.342437 IP 10.0.12.102.64752 > 216.239.32.116.443: UDP, length 1350
14:37:44.442644 IP 10.0.12.102.52742 > 216.239.32.116.443: Flags [S], seq 733044423, win 8192, options [mss 1386,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop,nop], length 0
14:37:44.449795 IP 17.252.156.200.5223 > 10.0.12.102.49466: Flags [S.], seq 3018115324, ack 3319498389, win 28960, options [mss 1413,sackOK,TS val 2255826576 ecr 263793670,nop,wscale 7], length 0
14:37:44.490598 IP 10.0.12.102.49466 > 17.252.156.200.5223: Flags [.], ack 1, win 2061, options [nop,nop,TS val 263807784 ecr 2255823391], length 0
14:37:44.518892 IP 10.0.12.102 > 10.0.12.2: ICMP echo request, id 24094, seq 294, length 64
14:37:44.519943 IP 17.57.145.102.443 > 10.0.12.102.49465: Flags [S.], seq 839710413, ack 616718581, win 29200, options [mss 1413], length 0
14:37:44.658272 IP 13.68.20.25.443 > 10.0.12.102.60120: Flags [R], seq 153298283, win 0, length 0
```

But I start a long pint to 54.239.31.91, as you see below, the packets has been sent through bwgla interface, but the IP address didn't translate into 10.0.12.102

```
[root@box2 ~]# tcpdump -i bwgla icmp and host 54.239.31.91 -nn
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on bwgla, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
14:43:30.544820 IP 219.141.235.xx > 54.239.31.91: ICMP echo request, id 62464, seq 3587, length 40
14:43:35.541710 IP 219.141.235.xx > 54.239.31.91: ICMP echo request, id 62464, seq 3588, length 40
14:43:40.557410 IP 219.141.235.xx > 54.239.31.91: ICMP echo request, id 62464, seq 3589, length 40
```

Below is the configuration of my iptablers POSTROUTING, pretty straight forward, right?

```
[root@box2 ~]# iptables -t nat -L -nv 
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 21831 packets, 1734K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 8898 packets, 636K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 6173 packets, 470K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 15815 packets, 1234K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
17679 1888K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      hphk    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 2938  204K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      zptled  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
16110 1039K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      bwgla   0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

**But why traffic headed to 54.239.31.91 is not translating, because some sort of connection cache, or any bugs?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Linux NAT has a connection cache (*conntrack*) and it applies even to "connectionless" streams such as UDP and ICMP. Only the first packet actually goes through your NAT rules – all subsequent packets will just do a conntrack lookup and apply the same translation (if any).

Your tcpdump shows ICMP requests with very high sequence numbers, indicating that this `ping` has been running for a long time – probably from before you added those NAT rules. If restarting `ping` does not help, use the **`conntrack`** tool to remove individual states or to flush the entire connection table.

```
conntrack -L

conntrack -F

conntrack -D -p icmp -d 54.239.31.91
```

Note that the exact same *conntrack* system is used for iptables `--state` and `--ctstate` filtering rules. So if you currently have connections filtered by `--state ESTABLISHED` or similar, flushing the conntrack cache will most likely interrupt them.